# Preventing redundant box labels for automultiplechoice numeric choices

Tags: tikz-pgf, auto-multiple-choice

Using automultiplechoice package. I'm trying to make a space efficient scannable response sheet for questions with digit inputs. The default \AMCcode and \AMCnumbericChoices print a digit to the right of every box. How can I print the digit either inside or just once preferably to the left of the digit boxes?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{automultiplechoice}    
\begin{document}
\begin{questionmultx}{Q01}
\AMCnumericChoices{1}{digits=3,sign=false,vertical=True,borderwidth=0pt,backgroundcol=lightgray,scoreexact=1}
\end{questionmultx}
\AMCcode{1}{2}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a source of `automultiplechoice`?

Comment: @Symbol1: you can build it from the sources at https://bitbucket.org/auto-multiple-choice/auto-multiple-choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `insidebox` package option (but wou will have to ask the students to fill the boxes completely):

```
\usepackage[insidebox]{automultiplechoice}
```

Also consider using the horizontal versions with `\AMCcodeH` and `vertical=False` in `\AMCnumericChoices`.